# Can I group by a column and resample a date?

Tags: python, pandas

I have some consumer purchase data that looks like

```
CustomerID  InvoiceDate
13654.0     2011-07-17 13:29:00
14841.0     2010-12-16 10:28:00
19543.0     2011-10-18 16:58:00
12877.0     2011-06-15 13:34:00
15073.0     2011-06-06 12:33:00
```

I'm interested in the rate at which customers purchase.  I'd like to group by each customer and then determine how many purchases were made in each quarter (let's say each quarter is every 3 months starting in January).

I could just define when each quarter starts and ends and make another column.  I'm wondering if I could instead use `groupby` to achieve the same thing.

Presently, this is how I do it:

```
r = data.groupby('CustomerID')

frames = []
for name,frame in r:

    f =frame.set_index('InvoiceDate').resample("QS").count()

    f['CustomerID']= name

    frames.append(f)


g = pd.concat(frames)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

```
In [43]: df.groupby(['CustomerID', pd.Grouper(key='InvoiceDate', freq='QS')]) \
           .size() \
           .reset_index(name='Count')
Out[43]:
   CustomerID InvoiceDate  Count
0     12877.0  2011-04-01      1
1     13654.0  2011-07-01      1
2     14841.0  2010-10-01      1
3     15073.0  2011-04-01      1
4     19543.0  2011-10-01      1
```

---

Is that what you want?

```
In [39]: df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='InvoiceDate', freq='QS')).count()
Out[39]:
             CustomerID
InvoiceDate
2010-10-01            1
2011-01-01            0
2011-04-01            2
2011-07-01            1
2011-10-01            1
```

Comment: Close.  I also want to group by the customer ID. I found a way to do it, thanks.

Comment: Much better.  Thanks!

Comment: @DemetriP, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the best I will be able to do:

```
data.groupby('CustomerID').apply(lambda x: x.set_index('InvoiceDate').resample('QS').count())
```